# Block user on webpage by time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web

I need some help figuring how to implement the following on my website. The website will allow a user to watch a television channel, but I need it to block the user after some period of time. (For example, a registered and activated user may be allowed several hours, but only for that user. I don't want all users to be blocked at the same instant I try to block one user. I think I want to use JavaScript to do this.

Original question, in case I missed something in the rewrite:

> I will be very pleased if this thing  I need will happen to me,you know guys I have a website that allow user to watch television channel so I need javascript that will block user after time.Example: if  user registered and ativeted so I need after somehours user being blocked automatically via javascript and  I dont want this to happen to all user in the same time may be by their adress .if there is any comment help me; Im sory for a bad english I dont understand english as well help me there  thank for your surpport guys)

Comment: What do you mean by "block"?

Comment: You can not do this in a secure way on the client-side. You will have to do this on the server by killing the video stream for that user.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use javascript for that? If so, a competent user could bypass your blockade. If you really want to block a user after some hours you might consider doing that on your server (probably in PHP).

If you just want to block users, and don't really mind if a few users bypass this, just write it in the comment and I am going to explain how you can archieve this!

EDIT: Javascript code:
It should work with this code, in the method *blockUser()* you can define what the browser should do to block the user, maybe just printing an alert every second or hiding all divs or ....
Hope I could help you!

EDIT2:
In this solution I am using an cookie called *timeLeft*. It stores the time in seconds which the user is able to view. With the first if (if(getCookie("timeLeft") == "")) I just create a new cookie if there's no cookie there yet. Then I call every second the method *subSecond*. It subtracts 1 from the current time and writes the new time in the cookie. If the time is zero (or less) the function *blockUser* is called in which you can add some additional javascript to make sure you blocked the user.
But again, this is only a solution for unexperienced users, users who knows a little bit of computers can bypass this block easily by deleting the cookie or setting the cookie to an higher value.

```
    var timeLeft;
    if(getCookie("timeLeft") == ""){ //cookie doesn't exist yet
        setCookie("timeLeft", 3*60*60, 365); //first argument: name of cookie
                                             //second argument: after how many seconds the user should be blocked (in this example 3 hours)
                                             //third argument: how long do you want to store this cookie in days (in this example 1 year)
    }
    timeLeft = getCookie("timeLeft");

    subSecond();

    function subSecond(){
        //1 second has past, let's remove it from our cookie
        timeLeft--;
        setCookie("timeLeft",timeLeft,"365");

        console.log(getCookie("timeLeft"));

        if(timeLeft <= 0) blockUser();

        //and now just open this method again in 1 second
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            subSecond(); 
        }, 1000);
    }

    function blockUser(){
    alert("BLOCKING");S
    }



    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: I want javascript perfect because my website using free server and not php I dont understand php anymore

Comment: Okay - sorry! Didn't know that, thanks for telling me. Now I added the javascript code, so it is an answer. Now it's ok, isn't it?

Comment: @Philipp Yes, you have made it an answer (although it could use some code explanation if you wanted to make it better).